# How to transform angular date-picker to popup-date-picker

Tags: angularjs, html, angular

i have this plunker and i would like to create the same angular date-picker-popup.
Do you have some ideas?

Thanks

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/cSKKgZW8t4z8c9yiwDx8?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Use `angularStrap` [see details here](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/datepickers)

Example usage would be similar to below example

```
<form name="datepickerForm" class="form-inline" role="form">
  <!-- Basic example -->
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': datepickerForm.date.$invalid}">
    <label class="control-label"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Date <small>(as date)</small></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedDate" name="date" bs-datepicker>
  </div>
  <!-- Custom example -->
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': datepickerForm.date2.$invalid}">
    <label class="control-label"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Date <small>(as number)</small></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedDateAsNumber" data-date-format="yyyy-MM-dd" data-date-type="number" data-min-date="02/10/86" data-max-date="today" data-autoclose="1" name="date2" bs-datepicker>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <!-- Date range example -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <i class="fa fa-arrows-h"></i> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Date range <small>(dynamic)</small></label><br>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="fromDate" data-max-date="{{untilDate}}" placeholder="From" bs-datepicker>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="untilDate" data-min-date="{{fromDate}}" placeholder="Until" bs-datepicker>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not the solution expected, my question is more simple, how can i to change my plunker to a popup solution? Thanks

Comment: well this is a better solution @SteVizzo

Comment: In my opinion the solution could be something like to add datepicker-popup attribute or something of similar...

Comment: why would you want to re invent the wheel ? when you already have a better suited lib